# MySQL database import error #1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a SQL database that I want to import using phplyadmin but I am getting this error.

```
CREATE TABLE  `wp_commentmeta` (

`meta_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`comment_id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
`meta_key` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`meta_value` LONGTEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (  `meta_id` ) ,
KEY  `comment_id` (  `comment_id` ) ,
KEY  `meta_key` (  `meta_key` ( 191 ) )
) ENGINE = Aria AUTO_INCREMENT =3843 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8          
PAGE_CHECKSUM =1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE =1 TRANSACTIONAL =1;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PAGE_CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 TRANSACTIONAL=1' at line 9

Comment: Try without ENGINE = Aria AUTO_INCREMENT =3843 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8          
PAGE_CHECKSUM =1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE =1 TRANSACTIONAL =1;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are not using [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/), change `ENGINE=Aria` to `ENGINE=MyISAM`(or `ENGINE=InnoDB`) and remove `PAGE_CHECKSUM=1` and `TRANSACTIONAL =1`;

Find an example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b33e77)