# Which PhpMyAdmin export settings can be changed to avoid errors exporting/importing between MySQL and MariaDB servers?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Using PhpMyAdmin, I am trying to import a Wordpress database into a MySQL server which was exported from a MariaDB server but there is an error as follows:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PAGE_CHECKSUM=1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2' at line 22

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30759674/325067) fixes the problem but involves manually editing all the offending statements in the exported SQL file.

Are there PhpMyAdmin export settings that could be modified to avoid these errors and avoid having to edit the SQL file after each export?

Comment: In fact, I found another question which seems to exactly be the same problem you are having.  Replace `Aria` with `MyISAM`, and remove `PAGE_CHECKSUM`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Thanks. I am going to modify my question slightly since my goal was to find out what to change in the PhpAdmin settings to make it work rather than having to mass edit the SQL file each time I need to do this. I will hopefully change it enough so that it is not a duplicate.

Comment: You should first try the suggestion of the duplicate link.  If it resolves your problem, then your question is actually a duplicate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Changing the first statement moves the error on to a later statement so it is indeed resolving the problem. However, as I said, I was looking for a solution that can be made by changing export settings in PhpAdmin. I suspect that would make it a ServerFault question rather than a StackOverflow one? Would you agree?

Comment: So there is a way to export a table using the Aria storage engine in MariaDB, but have the `CREATE TABLE` statement specify some other storage engine?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm looking into it now but still wondering if it is worthwhile to reopen the question differently-worded if it will perhaps be different enough to the other question. Even if the answer is PhpMyAdmin cannot do this, it may be helpful to document this. Before I edit the question, what are your thoughts on reopening and would Stackoverflow be the right place for a question essentially about PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL database import error #1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759313/mysql-database-import-error-1064)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I edited the question - I hope not inappropriately according to the rules - to better reflect what I want to know.